# Ionic 2 + Firebase Auth

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

New to firebase authentication and I'm trying to pass in as argument a FirebaseAuth object on my constructor but I keep getting the error that it cannot find the name 'FirebaseAuth'.

My imports seem to be correct and I have installed the necessary dependencies.

[image]

Any idea why this is giving me an error?

Answer (score 1):

Try `import {FirebaseAuth} from 'angularfire2';`

Basically drop the `@`